# Begginer struggle at format string

Tags: jcreator

It is telling me that String cannot be converted to system...
but I really don't know what mistake did i made... 
still very new on software development..
please help me...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Serioustake1 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int age;
        String a = "Donald John Trump" ,b = "Height :",c = "Age :", d = "Name : ";
        float height;   

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the height of president:");
        height=input.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Please enter the age of president:");
        age=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tPresident Details");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");

        System formatString = String.format("%-15s%-10s\n%-15s%-10.1f\n%-15s%-10d",
                                              d,a,b,height,c,age);
        System.out.print(formatString);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of **[String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))** is `String`

So change

```
   System formatString = String.format("%-15s%-10s\n%-15s%-10.1f\n%-15s%-10d",
                                          d,a,b,height,c,age);
```

to

```
   String formatString = String.format("%-15s%-10s\n%-15s%-10.1f\n%-15s%-10d",
                                          d,a,b,height,c,age);
```

Comment: Sure..but it needs time , it says i can accept it in 7 minutes